# find what values are between a range comparing 2 parts of the data set in R

Tags: r, range

I have been stuck on this problem for the last 2 days :(.
This is how my data set looks like.

```
        V1    V2 V3   V4     V5 V6
1 1.347256 1.347  1 3300  -3399  1
2 1.353107 1.353  2 4021  -5155  1
3 1.356644 1.357  3 4480  -6859  1
4 1.362766 1.363  2 6471 -11369  1
5 1.368889 1.369  4 5102  -6463  1
6 1.381361 1.381  2 4346  -2940  1



 1.347256 1.347  1 3301  -3395  2
 1.354150 1.354  1 3579  -5156  2
 1.356644 1.357  1 4478  -6863  2
 1.362766 1.363  1 6465 -11373  2
 1.368889 1.368  1 5103  -6463  2
 1.405488 1.405  1 1827  -3415  2
```

I want to compare the values in V2 when V6 is 1 and when V6 is 2. And need to exctact the values of the subset V6=1 that are within a range of +/- 0.003 of any value in the subset V6=2.

for example: the first 5 of V6==2 data should be considered, and somehow I want to retrieve the invormation in those rows.

Important: the 2 subsets have different lengths!

Here is my strategy.
I first subset the database.

```
ele1 <- subset(data, V6==1)
clus1 <- subset(ele1, V3==1)
ele2 <-subset(data, V6==2)
```

Then I thought that the best strategy it might be to get all the possible differences between the 2 subset. Then select those differences that will result in the range +/- 0.003.

Among all the trials that I did,
this is the best one:

```
for (i in 1:clus1$V2)
     for (j in 1:ele2$V2)
{
 diff<-(i-j)
if (diff>-0.003)& (diff<0.003)
{
res<-("number of row with the wanted walues")
}
}
```

Ok, I know that it is probably completely wrong (at least it maybe makes some of you laugh). 
I've just started to try to programm :).
Thank you for any type of imput!!

have fun

Comment: Please give example data that contains values `V6==2` and add the expected result to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer to your first questions.

```
V2_1 <- data$V2[data$V6==1]
V2_2 <- data$V2[data$V6==2]
```

Then have your way with those two vectors' worth of values.

To go any further, you'll have to edit your question for clarity.  I suspect you can do your rejection of `<0.003` values with judicious use of `all.equal` , setting the `tolerance` argument appropriately, or similarly with `cgwtools::approxeq` .(Disclaimer-I wrote the latter)

hmmmm... since you want to compare each element of one vector against each element of the other, perhaps something like this:

```
cmp <- abs(outer(V2_1, V2_2,"-"))
```

That'll give you a matrix of all possible differences.  Find the indices of matches:

```
cmp.match <- which (cmp < 0.003, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

And reject the values of `V2_1`, or `V2_2` which match those indices.

Comment: thanks, the data subset I chose it is slightly different just because aactually I need to compare only V3==1 of V6==1 with V6==2. However the principle is the same. I try to dig in the fuctions that you suggests. I have not tried them yet!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Dear Carl, all.equal just tells me that they differ but I cannot set an output that I can use afterwords. The function that you wrote looks really streightforward but it is only defined for equally-sized data frames...and mine do have different lengths!

Comment: Thanks Carl, pretty elegant and fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(ele1)) # you have to specify the number of loops
 {
  for (j in 1:nrow(ele2))
   {
    diff <- ele1[i,2] - ele2[j,2] # as V2 is the second column
    if ((diff > -0.003) & (diff < 0.003))
     {
      print(i,j)
     }
   }
 }
```

I'm also freshman in R, but maybe sth. like the code above does work?

Comment: A further shortcoming of your approach: with increasing length of your dataframe, this approach becomes slower and slower and the complexity increases exponentially. For example, if you have 2 variables with 3 values in each variable, you'll run 3^2 comparisons. If you have 500 values in each variable, you'll have to run 500^2 comparisons. That'll occupy your PC for a few minutes. I'm not sure if that works here, but maybe some kind of sorting algorithm might be more appropriate. Otherwise, it might be useful for you to think about, if you really have to compare each i with each j value.

Comment: This is a good point. It takes too long (my dataset are big). But I would not know how to say to look for only a set of values. Somenthing like look only between those value that have +/- 1.000.

Comment: That would just increase the complexity, because with that method you would look at first at differences between +/- 1.0 and afterwards again at diffs around 0.003.

I'm relatively sure, that some sort algorithms might help and that you maybe post such a question here at stackflow. If I remember correctly, with sorting algorithms the complexity might decrease a lot.

Comment: I tried the solution proposed by Carl Witthoft and it works fine, really fast. I just need a couple of extraline of code to find the selected rows back. Thanks for your help, it was important to clarify "for loop" in R to me. Best